# How can I run and stop IISExpress from jake

Tags: asp.net-mvc, integration-testing, iis-express, phantomjs, jake

I'm able to kick off IIS express to run my mvc 3 app with the following coffeescript line:

```
iisex = jake.createExec(['iisexpress /path:' + process.cwd() + ' /port:9090 /systray:false'], {printStdout: true})
#listening code here
iisex.run()
```

I then run some jasmine tests using

```
ex = jake.createExec(['phantomjs run_jasmine_test.coffee http://localhost:9090/app/applebees_testrunner.html'], {printStdout: true});
```

Test pass and now I want to kill IISExpress.

The problem is that now I have a long running process and the process wants me to 'press q' to stop the server.  Is there a way to send a q to the running process so that the server will stop?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps.  Is there a way for you to run the following command (needs cmd line opened with admin rights - to do this manually).
iisreset /stop